# Finding the position of current td cell when click on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to find the current cell that the user has clicked on. For  example if the user clicked on the first cell, I want to return 1. If they clicked on the tenth cell I want to return 10. There are 16 total cells in the table.

```
<html>
        <head>
        <title>Lights Out!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>

        <script type= "text/javascript">

        //The d
        var gameBoard = new Array(getTdCount())

        for(var i =0; i < getTdCount(); i++)
        {
            gameBoard[i] = 0;
        }





        function getTdCount()
        {
            return $("td").length;
        }

        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            $("#board tr td").hover(function()
            {
                $(this).css('border-color', '00FF33');
            },
            function()
            {
                $(this).css('border-color', 'black')
            })

            var $offProtoType = $('#offprototype').css('display', 'block').removeAttr('id')     
            $('td').append($offProtoType)

            $("#board tr td").click(function()
            {
                $("img", this).attr('src', 'on.png')

            })

        });


        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
        td
        {
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:black;
            background-color:black;
            float:left;
        }

        </style>


        </head>
        <body>

        <img style = "display:none" id="offprototype"  src ="off.png">
        <img style = "display:none" id="onprototype"  src ="on.png">

        <table id="board" border="3" bgcolor="black" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Shuffle" onclick="change()"/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
var $tds = $('#board tr td');
$tds.click(function(){
    // Gets the 0 based index, and add 1:
    var num = $tds.index(this) + 1; 
    $("img", this).attr('src', 'on.png') 
});
```

We first cache the results for the `#board tr td` search, so we don't have to look it up on each click.

Next, we get use the `index` function to find the index of the current `td` out of the full result of `td` elements.

Last, we add 1 since `index` returns a `0` based count.

**Update: jQuery 1.4**

This is not an instance were we can use the new `index()` feature of jQuery 1.4. `index()` without parameters, gets the index of the element from the context of its siblings. In this case, we need it in the context of all the `td` elements in the table, not just its siblings.

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Comment: With jQuery 1.4 you could just do  var num=$(this).index() + 1;

Comment: @patrick this is not a case where we can use that shorthand. I updated my answer to provide explanation as to why not.

Comment: You're right. I didn't read the question closely enough and for some reason assumed it was merely on a per-row basis. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var cells = $('#board td')
cells.click(function() { alert(cells.index(this) + 1); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The cellIndex property can be used.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-82915075

Be aware: There is a bug in Safari 2 and Konqueror where cellIndex is always 0. In that case, a feature test and a fallback can be used.